# How to stop creating .DS_Store on Mac?

Tags: macos

I'm developing sites on mac and every time I create some folder (or file in that folder) .DS_Store is created in that folder.

How to prevent creating .DS_Store  file ?

Comment: Dislike :) What should I use than?

Comment: @CroiOS Terminal + VIM

Comment: It was a comment as no real alternative - in theory you could use the Terminal only or other tools e.g. editors ( or I think Path Finder as a file browser) but in practice you are stuck with these files

Comment: Just ignore the file in your version control system

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple hardware and software - best fit would be Ask Different.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `.DS_Store` files are only created when you look at the folder in Finder, so the only way to "prevent them from being created" is to not use finder.

Comment: Check [https://github.com/xiaozhuai/odourless](https://github.com/xiaozhuai/odourless), I made a tool for preventing .DS_Store.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Its is possible by using [mach_inject](https://github.com/rentzsch/mach_inject). Take a look at [Death to .DS_Store](http://www.aorensoftware.com/blog/2011/12/24/death-to-ds_store/)

> I found that overriding **HFSPlusPropertyStore::FlushChanges()** with a
>   function that simply did nothing, successfully prevented the creation
>   of .DS_Store files on both Snow Leopard and Lion.

[DeathToDSStore source code](https://github.com/snielsen/DeathToDSStore)

**NOTE:** On 10.11 you can not inject code into system apps.

Comment: Please could you provide some bash I can copy and paste into my shell. This solution requires quite a bit of engagement with the literature.

Comment: You can use [DeathToDSStore.app](http://www.aorensoftware.com/Downloads/Files/DeathToDSStore.zip)

Comment: Is there a 2019 solution? As DeathToDSStore doesn't seem to be working on latest MacOS's anymore...

Comment: @JKL I am not aware of any working solution.

Answer (score 43):

Please install http://asepsis.binaryage.com/ and then reboot your mac.

ASEPSIS redirect all .DS_Store on your mac to /usr/local/.dscage

After that, You could recursively delete all .DS_Store from your Mac.

```bash
find ~ -name ".DS_Store" -delete
```

or

```bash
find <your path> -name ".DS_Store" -delete
```

You should repeat procedure after each major Mac update.

Comment: Note for Mac OSX 10.10 you should upgrade Xcode Command Line Tools and after that manually run in terminal like root or with sudo the following command xcrun --find codesign. Manually accept License term and agreement and the you could continue asepsis installation

Comment: After each system upgrate needs reinstalation of latest version.

Comment: "Asepsis implements a system-wide daemon asepsisd whose purpose is to monitor system-wide folder renames (or deletes) and mirror those operations in the prefix folder"
This was written on Asepsis' page. Is it really required to recursively delete the .DS_store files?

Comment: "Please install asepsis" Please could you show me some bash commands so I can just copy and paste these into my shell?

Comment: # download installation package
wget http://downloads.binaryage.com/Asepsis-1.5.1.dmg
# mount volume
hdiutil attach Asepsis-1.5.1.dmg
# install
sudo installer -pkg /Volumes/Asepsis/Asepsis.pkg -target /
# unmount volume
sudo hdiutil detach /Volumes/Asepsis
# remove installation package
rm Asepsis-1.5.1.dmg

Comment: No additional updates under EL Capitan or later (because System Integrity Protection (SIP)) - http://asepsis.binaryage.com/#sip

Comment: There is still a way to get Asepsis working under El Capitan.  I've documented the steps here:
http://pixelcog.com/blog/2016/disable-ds_store-in-el-capitan/

Answer (score 40):

**NOTE**: *"Asepsis is no longer under active development and supported under OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) and later."*

---

Here's a [comprehensive review](http://www.chrisnovoa.com/os-x-lion-ds_store-disabling/) of your options. [Asepsis](http://asepsis.binaryage.com/) (the second solution mentioned) seems to be what you're looking for, it re-routes .DS_Store creation to a unified cache instead of being located on every folder.

Comment: In case the link ever goes bad, the two most likely options listed on that site are Asepsis (redirects created files) and DeathToDSStore (prevents file creation, disabling some Finder features), both of which are described in answers on this page.  The other options deal with network drives and external drives - both of which only solve part of the problem.

Comment: @emmanuel: This *does* include the essential parts: the name of a program and the specific feature it provides to solve the problem.

Answer (score 36):

Open Terminal. Execute this command:

```
defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores true
```

Either restart the computer or log out and back in to the user account.

for more informations:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208209

Comment: only applies to network filesystems

Comment: updated link: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208209

Comment: `defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteUSBStores -bool true` is the same for USB drives.

Answer (score -7):

Put following line into your ".profile" file.

Open .profile file and copy this line

```
find ~/ -name '.DS_Store' -delete
```

When you open terminal window it will automatically delete your .DS_Store file  for you.

Comment: running this at login slowed things down, so I just made this alias: `alias nomore='find ./ -iname .DS_Store -delete'`

Comment: So, is [/irony off] turning your irony off or ending your irony being off making it turn on?

Comment: This is a great way to kill (productive) time while mac searches hundreds of K's of files on disk.

Answer (score -10):

this file starts to appear when you choose the system shows you the hidden files: $defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
If you run this command disapear
$defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE
Use terminal

Comment: The question asks how to stop the files from being created, not how to hide them.

Answer (score -10):

the function

```
find ~/ -name '.DS_Store' -delete
```

, removed the .DS store files temporarily. But am not sure , whether the files will came back on the Mac.
Also i noticed something peculiar, the "DS_Store" start coming to the Mac after installing 'ATOM'. So guys please make it sure to scan properly your third party software before installing them.
Best

Comment: .DS_Store files are created by OSX Finder

Comment: The question asks how to stop the files from being created. This answer is how to delete them. Additionally, `ATOM` is not creating the files. The `Finder` application creates them when visiting a folder to store icon positions, selected view for the folder, background image, etc.  `DS_Store`, DS is Desktop Services.

Answer (score -15):

If you want the `.DS_Store` files to become invisible (they still exist but can't be seen) then run the following command in the "Terminal" window:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE; killall Finder
```

This will set the system default to stop showing these files on your Desktop and elsewhere. It will also restart the Finder in order to make this change visible (especially on your Desktop).

Comment: That's not answering the question that was asked.

Comment: Hiding the showing of hidden files is not removing the creation of .DS_Store files, which is the question that was asked. This is a terrible answer.

Comment: The question asks how to stop the files from being created. This solution hides them (and other files) only in Finder.