# Unable to ignore .DS_Store files in DVC

Tags: dvc

I use DVC to track my media files. I use MacOS and I want".DS_Store" files to be ignored by DVC. According to DVC documentation I can achieve it with  [.dvcignore](https://dvc.org/doc/user-guide/dvcignore). I created `.dvcignore` file with ".DS_Store" rule. However every time ".DS_Store" is created `dvc status` still says that content has changed

Here is the little test to reproduce my issue:

```
$ git init
$ dvc init

# create directory to store data
# and track it's content with DVC
$ mkdir data
$ dvc add data

# Ignore .DS_Store files created by MacOS
$ echo ".DS_Store" > .dvcignore

# create .DS_Store in data dir
$ touch "data/.DS_Store"
```

If I understand DVC documentation correctly then `dvc status` should print something like "Pipeline is up to date. Nothing to reproduce". However `dvc status` gives me:

```
data.dvc:
        changed outs:
                modified:           data
```

How I can really ignore ".DS_Store" files?

**UPDATE:** The .dvcignore support noticeably improved in latest versions and the problem is no more relevant.

Comment: Maybe use a pattern to ignore in all folders: `**/.DS_Store`.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current implementation of `.dvcignore` is very limited. Read more on it [here](https://dvc.org/doc/user-guide/dvcignore).

Please, mention that you are interested in this feature here - https://github.com/iterative/dvc/issues/1876. That would help our team to prioritize issues properly.

The possible workaround for now would be to use one of these approaches - [How to stop creating .DS_Store on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18015978/how-to-stop-creating-ds-store-on-mac)

Answer (score 2):

It seems this has been since fixed/implemented!

```
$ dvc init --no-scm
...
$ mkdir data
$ dvc add data
WARNING: 'data' is empty.
Saving information to 'data.dvc'.                                                                                                                            
$ echo ".DS_Store" > .dvcignore
$ touch "data/.DS_Store"
$ tree -a data
data
└── .DS_Store

0 directories, 1 file
$ dvc status
Data and pipelines are up to date.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It indeed has been fixed since I have asked my question.